# Xamarin How to initialize contentview's content?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

There is a stack layout in the content view.

When a specific button is clicked, I want to remove the content of the Contentview and put it in another content. For stacklayout, calling childen.clear() clears the contents inside. For contentview, how should I use it?

Comment: Set it to null or an empty view

Comment: For more info you can refer to the doc: [Xamarin.Forms ContentView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/contentview) by official.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Contentview.Content` to `null` just as Jason said.

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
   // set Contentview.Content to null          
   contentview.Content=null;

   //add other view to ContentView's Content           
   contentview.Content = (
          new Label{ 
              Text = "this is a new label",                    
              BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                });        
}
```

Comment: Is my answer helpful to your question?